# How to Ensure The Full Optional Group is Selected

Tags: regex

I have a short code that I am segmenting with the pipe "|" symbol and trying to match with RegEx.

The issue is everything after the 2nd segment is optional, but needs to follow a specific capture group format.

For example the 3rd segment must be a number range such as 5-10. There can be an unlimited number of segments after that that can contain any character except a pipe or a closing bracket.

The following expression works to capture everything I want:

```
\[tag:( )?(img|image)[ |]{1,3}[^|\]]+([ |]{1,3}[0-9]+-[0-9]+)?([ |]{1,3}[^|\]]*)*]
```

Unfortunately it also captures tags that are incorrectly formated.

```
[tag: img | some tag content, I want ] <---- Should Match
[tag: img | some tag content, I want |] <---- Should Not Match

[tag: img | some tag content, I want | 10-30 | optional-option ] <---- Should Match
[tag: img | some tag content, I want | 10-30 || optional-option ] <---- Should Not Match
```

How can I enforce that an optional group is captured in its entirety?

Bonus question: Why does adding a $ to the end cause nothing to match?

Comment: Bonus answer: `$` does not prevent matching if the match is at the end of string, see https://regex101.com/r/3ZNixv/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `[ |]{1,3}` are faulty here, as you want to make sure the `|` is single and is wrapped with whitespaces. Also, the last `[^|\]]*` allows *zero* or more chars other than pipe and bracket, you need to require at least one with the `+` quantifier.

You can use

```php
\[tag:( )?(img|image)\s*\|\s*[^]|]+(\s*\|\s*[0-9]+-[0-9]+)?(\s*\|\s*[^]|]+)*]
```

Or, if you want the pipes to be enclosed with single spaces:

```php
\[tag:( )?(img|image) \| [^]|]+( \| [0-9]+-[0-9]+)?( \| [^]|]+)*]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EVB2jG/1/%5D).

*Details*:

- `\[tag:` - `[tag:` text
- `( )?` - An optional Group 1: a space
- `(img|image)` - `img` or `image` word
- `|`  - a  `|`  text
- `[^]|]+` - one or more chars other than `]` and `|`
- `( \| [0-9]+-[0-9]+)?` - An optional Group 2:  `|`  text, one or more digits, `-`, one or more digits
- `( \| [^]|]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of the capturing group3:  `|`  text, and then one or more chars other than `]` and `|`
- `]` - a `]` char.

Comment: Yes you are correct I now see how that would create the issue. The first seems to do the trick, but I had to change the [^]|] bits to [^|\]] thank you.

Comment: @user10012 Do you work in JavaScript? Then yes. In ECMAScript flavor, `]` inside a character class must always be escaped.

Comment: It's actually in PHP, but yes brackets need to be escaped.

Comment: @user10012 No, in PHP PCRE regex, you do not need to escape `]` inside `[...]` when it is the first char in the character class.

Comment: Interesting. Another thing I did not know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If in the optional part the third part has to be 10-30 you could make the outer group optional, and inside that group first match the digits-digits part and then make the rest optional.

If you add `<---- Should Match` at the end of the data, and you add `$` at the end of the patter, the pattern does not match anymore as the dollar sign asserts the end of the string.

```
\[tag: ?(img|image) ?\|[^][|]*( *\| *[0-9]+-[0-9]+( *\|[^][|]+)?)?]
```

- `\[` Match the opening `[`
- `tag: ?(img|image) ?\|` Match `tag:` optional space, capture *img* or *image* in **group 1**, optional space and `|`
- `[^][|]*` Match 0+ chars other than `[` `]` `\`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `*\| *[0-9]+-[0-9]+` Match optional spaces `|` optional space and digits-digits
  - `( *\|[^][|]+)*?` Optional capture **group 3**
- `)?` Close group 1 and make it optional
- `]` Match the closing `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QkXBb6/1)